# Convergence of a sequence of roots of continous functions

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms, uniform-convergence

Let $(f^n,n\in\mathbb{N})$ be a sequence of complex continous functions so that $f^n(u)\longrightarrow f(u)$ uniformly to a complex continous function f if $n \longrightarrow \infty$. I addition I know that $log(f^n(u))\longrightarrow log(f(u))$ uniformly if $n \longrightarrow \infty$.

Why can we follow now also that $f^n(u)^{1/k}\longrightarrow f(u)^{1/k}$ uniformly for every k as $n \longrightarrow \infty$?

I don't know why the "log"-convergence statement is neccessary to proof that.
Can someone give me a hint?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Functions are non negative? If not, the suggestion is false. If yes, use that log and sqrt[k] are continuous

Comment: All functions are complex functions that don't take the value 0. So when sqrt[k] is a continous function, why can't I write $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{f^{(n)}}^{1/k}=(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{f^{(n)}})^{1/k}=f^{1/k}$$ from the beginning? why do I need the statement of the "log"-convergence? I definitly need it. it is stated in the script.

Comment: The problem is that (any particular branch of) $\sqrt[k]{z}$ is not continuous at a branch cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $z^{1/k} = \exp(\log(z)/k)$.  This is multi-valued in general, but presumably you're using some particular branch of log here.

Let's suppose this is the principal branch, so that $-\pi < \arg(z) = \text{Im}(\log(z)) \le \pi$, and $\arg(z^{1/k}) = \arg(z)/k$.  Let $Q_j$ be the four quadrants of $\mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$, $j=1\ldots 4$, with the negative real axis included in the second quadrant but not the third.
Take $N$ large enough so that for $n \ge N$, $|\log(f^n(u)) - \log(f(u))| < \pi/2$.  Thus $f^n(u)$ may be in the same quadrant as $f(u)$ or a neighbouring one, except that we can't have one in $Q_2$ and the other in $Q_3$.  The function $z \to z^{1/k}$ is unifomly
continuous on $Q_1 \cup Q_2 \cup Q_4$ and
also uniformly continuous on $Q_3 \cup Q_4 \cup Q_1$.  Thus $f^n(u)^{1/k} \to f(u)^{1/k}$ uniformly on each $f^{-1}(Q_i)$, and therefore uniformly on the union of all of them.